# Book about three magical children in an empire where magic is banned?

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this trilogy of books some years ago (must be at least 5-6 years ago; perhaps as many as 10). Three children, two boys and a girl, who have been selectively bred over generations to express a magical power which is banned in the world. It's a kind of cult obsession within a small town that's part of an expansionist empire that I want to call 'the concord' (but Google makes me think that's wrong).

These children have their magic 'emerge' in early adolescence. One boy is the most powerful and shares his name with another magic user of ages past, but he's also arrogant and quite sociopathic.

This boy ends up raping his 'sister' (the girl of the three) and she gives birth to an even more adept son.

Eventually the empress (or equivalent) learns of these magic users but boldly decides to support them publicly in the hopes they can be useful in future wars for this empire. There's a militaristic religious sect violently opposed to this who has a female leader hell bent on destroying these magical abominations.

Rapist brother is outcast from the group and learns to somehow raise the dead to fight for him. He uses this power to ally with an enemy of the empire which causes a war which essentially breaks it. He's defeated at the end but at great cost. The surviving magical children decide to withdraw from the world as it's clearly not ready for them.

The rape is around the end of book one. The rise of the dead as a threat is around 2/3 of the way in book two, and I think book three is just the full on war and subsequently spiral of worsening events. (I think!) Slim chance the whole story was just two massive books, seemed very detailed at the time.

Driving me mad not being able to find them!

Comment: In roughly which year/s did you read these books, and when do you think they might've been published?

Comment: The abovementioned events happened over the course of the trilogy? Do you know approximately where in the books they happened?

Comment: The rape is around the end of book one. The rise of the dead  as a threat is around 2/3 of the way in book two, and I think book 3 is just the full on war and subsequently spiral of worsening events. (I think!) Slim chance the whole story was just two massive books, seemed very detailed at the time.

Comment: You've added a bounty, but no additional information that might help people find the story. You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Incredibly, I managed to find out the book by trawling a long, long way back through my Amazon order history. Published in 2005 (and I read it in 2006), the book series is [The Ascendants of Estorea](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Cry-Newborn-Ascendants-Estorea-GOLLANCZ/dp/0575076208/) by James Barclay.

The empire is called the **Conquord** (so close... if only I'd known the spelling), and to my surprise the book is centred around four children, not three, so that detail was wrong. It's also two books, not a trilogy (but somewhat understandable, each book is ~600 pages).

Off I go to re-read. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I will also try to ignore my worrying perception of time where "5-6 years, maybe 10" is actually 16...

Comment: Oh, I still think that about 1987...