# 2 part novel series early to mid 2000s with 4 children born with powers

Tags: story-identification, novel

2 novels. Fantasy. Pretty sure it's 4 children that are born with powers. One a boy turns bad and turns out to be the most powerful. The armies are described as well in my mind like Roman soldiers but not set in Roman times. 2nd novel the boy is able to raise the dead for his army. Also tries to sleep with the girl and she becomes pregnant and gives birth to his son and is also powerful. Pretty sure the boy he was killed at the end by the female by her using her powers and pinning him down by using the earth around him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall the cover art or any character/place names?

Comment: No nothing at all. I have been racking my brain for few days. Pretty sure the title of the 2nd novel had dead in it, as that was the one he was able to raise the dead. Her getting pregnant by him only popped into my head a few hrs ago

Comment: Likely a duplicate of this question; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260929/book-about-three-magical-children-in-an-empire-where-magic-is-banned. The second book in [the series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/44185-the-ascendants-of-estorea) is "A Shout for the Dead"

Comment: Maaaate you absolute hero that's it hahaha. Woooooow. Thank you sooo much